# Elasticsearch cannot index array of integers

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

## Given mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "user_ids": {"type": "integer"}
        }
    }
}
```

## Observations:

- Index `{"user_ids": 1}`, and data will show up correctly
- Index `{"user_ids": "x"}`, and error is thrown `failed to parse field [user_ids] of type [integer] in document`, indicating that mapping is working correctly
- However, indexing `{"user_ids": [1]}` just clears the field, without throwing error.

## Question:

- Why does this happen and how can I index arrays of integers?

## Extra:

- I removed all `settings` config, doesn't change anything
- I tried `keyword` type, doesn't change anything
- If relevant, I use latest [opensearch-py](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-py/releases/tag/1.1.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's my own error: I was using [elasticsearch-head](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) for quick checking of values, and they don't support displaying of array values :/ Once I double checked with queries, they came back correct.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, its better to use kibana dev tools or postman :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what do you mean by clear the field, also indexing array of integers works perfectly fine as shown in below example, hope you are following same requests.

```
put <index-name>/_doc/1
{
    "user_ids": [
        1,2,3
    ]
}
```

And get API returns, all the integers in the array.

```
GET <index-name>/_doc/1
    "_source": {
        "user_ids": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    }
}
```